# PySpark slice dataset adding a column until a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

I have to add a column with a starting date based on a determinate condition:

```
STATUS.isin('CREATED', 'CREATED AGAIN')
```

For each ID, I wanna start from a date where status is `CREATION` or `CREATE AGAIN` and I wanna reproduce dataset adding a new column partitioning for `TIME` window.

For example:

INPUT:

| ID | $ | STATUS | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **050** | **CREATED** | **2021-11-01** |
| 1 | 120 | ATTEMPTING | 2021-11-01 |
| 1 | 130 | VALID | 2021-11-01 |
| 1 | 200 | OK | 2021-11-02 |
| 1 | **100** | **CREATED AGAIN** | **2021-11-03** |
| 1 | 160 | OK | 2021-11-03 |
| 1 | 200 | ONGOING | 2021-11-04 |
| 1 | 300 | OK | 2021-11-05 |
| 1 | 1000 | FINAL | 2021-11-06 |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |

OUTPUT:

| ID | $ | STATUS | TIME | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 050 | **CREATED** | **2021-11-01** | **2021-11-01** |
| 1 | 120 | ATTEMPTING | 2021-11-01 | **2021-11-01** |
| 1 | 130 | VALID | 2021-11-01 | **2021-11-01** |
| 1 | 200 | OK | 2021-11-02 | **2021-11-01** |
| 1 | 100 | **CREATED AGAIN** | **2021-11-03** | ***2021-11-03*** |
| 1 | 160 | OK | 2021-11-03 | ***2021-11-03*** |
| 1 | 200 | ONGOING | 2021-11-04 | ***2021-11-03*** |
| 1 | 300 | OK | 2021-11-05 | ***2021-11-03*** |
| 1 | 1000 | FINAL | 2021-11-06 | ***2021-11-03*** |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column `group` using a cumulative conditional sum then create column `START_DATE` as `first("TIME")` over Window partitioned by `ID` + `group`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("TIME")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("ID", "group").orderBy("TIME")

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "group",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("STATUS").isin(['CREATED', 'CREATED AGAIN']), 1)).over(w1)
).withColumn(
    "START_DATE",
    F.first("TIME").over(w2)
).drop("group")

df1.show()
#+---+----+-------------+----------+----------+
#| ID|   $|       STATUS|      TIME|START_DATE|
#+---+----+-------------+----------+----------+
#|  1| 050|      CREATED|2021-11-01|2021-11-01|
#|  1| 120|   ATTEMPTING|2021-11-01|2021-11-01|
#|  1| 130|        VALID|2021-11-01|2021-11-01|
#|  1| 200|           OK|2021-11-02|2021-11-01|
#|  1| 100|CREATED AGAIN|2021-11-03|2021-11-03|
#|  1| 160|           OK|2021-11-03|2021-11-03|
#|  1| 200|      ONGOING|2021-11-04|2021-11-03|
#|  1| 300|           OK|2021-11-05|2021-11-03|
#|  1|1000|        FINAL|2021-11-06|2021-11-03|
#+---+----+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank u Black, so precious! Just an update at my question: instead of taking the STATUS CREATED, if I want to take the FIRST DATE (first row) or the status CREATED-AGAIN, how should I do?

Comment: @Jresearcher sorry it's not clear to me. what do you mean by "_taking `CREATED-AGAIN` instead of `STATUS CREATED`_"?

Comment: Instead of ---> STATUS = CREATED
I would to take FIRST STATUS (First Row based on timestamp)!

Comment: I have created another temporany column with "yes" like this:

withColumn('tmp', F.when((F.row_number().over(w1)).isin(1) | F.col('STATUS_COD').isin('CREATED AGAIN'), 1).otherwise(0))

Then i proceed with ur solution --> F.sum(F.when(F.col("tmp").isin(1), 1)).over(w1)
)